# How do i use more than one delimiter?

Tags: python, excel, csv, worksheet

So, i'm trying to create a way to convert a tsv file to csv, but already with tab "\t" and delimiter= ' ', 
there is a way of doing that?

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

tsv_file = '1.tsv'
xlsx_file = '1.xlsx'

workbook = Workbook(xlsx_file)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

tsv_reader = csv.reader(open(tsv_file,'rt'),delimiter="\t")

for row, data in enumerate(tsv_reader):
    worksheet.write_row(row, 0, data)    

workbook.close()`
```

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what you are trying to do but delimiters are only a single char. If you are looking to ignore the whitespace after a delimiter you can set `skipinitialspace=True`.

Comment: I want to set the worksheet with a space delimiter and /t (tab)

Comment: If your delimiter is a `\t` or a space then you will need to do some preprocessing because `csv` only deals with a single char delimiter.